# Can I get my paycheck before I leave on vacation?

Tags: vacation

I'm leaving for vacation and will be out of state but payday is while I'm gone do I get my check early?

Comment: Have you checked with HR?  Your manager?

Comment: No HR dept and manager says after I get back which has never been true in the past

Comment: How big is your company?  (If there is no HR, then it is small?)  In other words, is the payroll run something that is done manually or automatically?  I'm guessing you do not have direct deposit?

Answer (score 5):

If direct deposit is not an option, it's OK to use credit cards in the meantime and then just pay them off when you get the paycheck later. It doesn't matter since the money will come out of the same place eventually (your bank acct).

I am not sure legal rights are relevant here. The employer has nothing to do with the fact that you decided to go on vacation before payday. Their responsibility is to pay you on the payday, rather than when it's convenient to you based on your vacation plans...

That said, I hope you are able to use other funds or savings to hold you over during your time off. Good luck!